# Change button background color based on previous color

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-button

I have a very simple problem

consider I'm retrieving a string value online using `getText()` Method

Now depending upon value of string I have set my button background to red and blue.

If string value is red then button background is red and if it is blue then blue.

Now if I implement `onClicklistener` to same button I would like to changes it's Background color. If it was Red then change it to blue and if it was blue then change it to red as long as user presses key.

```
 mSolved = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_solved); 
 mSolved.setText(g.getColorvalue()); 

 if("Blue".equals(holder.mSolved.getText())){
  mSolved.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
 }
 if("Red".equals(holder.mSolved.getText())){
  .mSolved.setBackgroundColor(RED);
 }

mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(Background color is already BLue)
 {
     change to Red
 }
 else
 {
    Change to Blue
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use FLAG variable to implement the logic

Comment: How can you give me some example?

Comment: Check the answer. Use FLAG variables similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FLAG variables. Something similar to this.

```
mSolved = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_solved); 
mSolved.setText(g.getColorvalue()); 

boolean IS_BLUE = false;
boolean IS_RED = false;

if("Blue".equals(holder.mSolved.getText())){
   mSolved.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
   IS_BLUE = true;
}
if("Red".equals(holder.mSolved.getText())){
   mSolved.setBackgroundColor(RED);
   IS_RED  = true;
}

mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     if(IS_BLUE)
     {
     mSolved.setBackgroundColor(RED);
     IS_RED  = true;
     IS_BLUE = false;
     }
    else if(IS_RED)
    {
    mSolved.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
    IS_BLUE = true;
    IS_RED  = false; 

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    mSolved = (Button) findViewById(R.id.book_solved);
    mSolved.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009900"));
    mSolved.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View tView) {


            ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) mSolved.getBackground();

            int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
           // Log.i("INFO", "find color value for new color " + colorId);
            if (colorId == -3407872) {  // color is read
                mSolved.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009900"));
            }
            else {

                mSolved.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cc0000"));

            }

        }
    });
```